# Override View() in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the follow base controller-

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
     protected string BaseUrl = "URL";
}
```

All other controller inherit the above base controller-

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{       
    public ActionResult Something()
    {
        ViewBag.BaseUrl = base.BaseUrl;
        return View();
    }
}
```

I don't want to write `ViewBag.BaseUrl = base.BaseUrl;` in every controller action method. Rather, I would to automatically pass this base url to the related view. Is it possible by overriding `View()`?

An example would be better for me.

Comment: But if doing that is possible that would  totally be against the MVC "separation of concerns" concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all controllers derive this then just put it in here:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
     protected string BaseUrl = "URL";
     public BaseController()
     {
         ViewBag.BaseUrl = base.BaseUrl;
     }   
}
```

I would even make it private if I do not want inheriting classes to overwrite it.

Comment: Is that so simple!! Thanks a lot.